# Add arrow navigation to tabs

Tags: jquery

I like to add a previous and next button navigation to the tabs, but can not figure out how to make it happen. I have set up the tab navigation and a basic click function for the previous and next button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  })

  $('#previous').click(function() {})

  $('#next').click(function() {})

})
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
  line-height: 1.6
}
.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.tabs {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.tabs li {
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.tabs li.current {
  background: #ededed;
  color: #222;
}
ul.arrownavigation {
  list-style: none;
}
ul.arrownavigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.arrownavigation li:active {
  background: #444;
}
ul.arrownavigation li.disabled {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 15px;
}
.tab-content.current {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <ul class="arrownavigation">
    <li id="previous">Previous</li>
    <li id="next">Next</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
    Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>

</div>
<!-- container -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  })

  $('#previous').click(function() {
    if($('ul.tabs li.current').prev().length != 0 ){
    $('ul.tabs li.current').removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current').click();
}
  })

  $('#next').click(function() {
 if($('ul.tabs li.current').next().length != 0 ){
    $('ul.tabs li.current').removeClass('current').next().addClass('current').click();
  }
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
  line-height: 1.6
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.tabs li {
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.tabs li.current {
  background: #ededed;
  color: #222;
}

ul.arrownavigation {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.arrownavigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.arrownavigation li:active {
  background: #444;
}

ul.arrownavigation li.disabled {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <ul class="arrownavigation">
    <li id="previous">Previous</li>
    <li id="next">Next</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
    Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>

</div>
<!-- container -->
```

You need to add only following code

```
    $('#previous').click(function() {
if($('ul.tabs li.current').prev().length != 0 ){
    $('ul.tabs li.current').removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current').click();
}
      });

    $('#next').click(function() {
if($('ul.tabs li.current').next().length != 0 ){
    $('ul.tabs li.current').removeClass('current').next().addClass('current').click();
        }
  });

      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this link, maybe it helps you or gives you some idea to change your code and make it works: http://www.small-software-utilities.com/2011/05/add-navigation-arrows-to-jquery-tabs/